# Training Tesseract: how to handle multiple whitespace characters in training images

Tags: ocr, tesseract, training-data

I am finetuning tesseract. I am using [tesstrain](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesstrain). When creating the ground truth files, how should I handle multiple whitespace characters?

a.tiff
[image]

There are two whitespaces between "(f)" and "any". I have no idea how many are between "30" and "(f)". Should I:

1. Attempt to provide the correct number of whitespaces? (in a.gt.txt)
2. Just use 1 whitespace between words always?
3. It doesn't make a difference.

I've seen on other tangentially related questions that when doing the inference, there is an [option to preserve interword space](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/d72c2b14a5805952cc01fd99ec64f7abd99ca47c/src/ccmain/tesseractclass.h#L1000). Maybe that makes a difference:

Comment: Currently facing the same problem: Did you find a "solution"? Right now, I am using option 2.

Comment: @Colle I just trained it on individual words in the end instead of full lines of words. Worked pretty well.